# VBA macro is not executed when worksheet cell is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I want a all the cells that are filled with content in column "D" of a worksheet to be named "SubGroups". For this I've created a macro that names that range of cells. It is supposed to be called everytime the worksheet is changed.

Here's the code. It isn't even executed when the worksheet changes. I inserted it inside the window that opens when I right click on the worksheet name, in the bottom of the screen, and the click in "view code".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("D:D")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
Dim lastRowWithContentInC As Integer
lastRowWithContentInC = getLastRowWithContentInColumn(4, Workbooks("Grupos e sub-grupos"))
If lastRowWithContentInC > 1 Then
    Range("D2:D" & LTrim(Str(lastRowWithContentInC))).Name = "SubGrupos"
Else
    Range("D2").Name = "SubGrupos"
End If
End If
End Function
```

I've also tried putting it inside "Worksheet_SelectionChange" procedure but it isn't executed either.

Comment: Make sure events are enabled - type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate window and hit enter.

Comment: FYI `Range(Target.Address)` is the same as `Target`

Comment: Immediate window? where's it? Is it in the same window that opens when I click in view code, after right clicking in the plan's name? And where in that window? Before any function or sub?

Comment: https://trumpexcel.com/vba-immediate-window/

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to be in one of two places:

A sub in the Worksheet-class, like in your example above:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Debug.Print "Worksheet_Change"
End Sub
```

Or a sub in the Workbook class, but then it runs when *any* sheet changes, so make sure the `Sh`-object is the correct one:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "Workbook_SheetChange: sheet " & Sh.Name
End Sub
```

Don't know if it is a typo, but your code does not compile. A Sub needs to end with `End Sub`, not `End Function`.

Try my sample code in your workbook and make sure it runs OK - `Debug.Print` prints messages to the Immediate window, so you can see that it runs without debugging.

When you have it running ok, just add your code in the sub.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Change the Range Reference of a Name

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1` e.g. in the *Project Explorer*: `Sheet1(Grupos e sub-grupos)`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ChangeRangeOfName Target, "D2", "SubGrupos", True
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1` (*Insert>Module*)**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeRangeOfName( _
        ByVal Target As Range, _
        ByVal FirstCellAddress As String, _
        ByVal RangeName As String, _
        Optional ByVal ShowMessages As Boolean = False)
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    
    ' Reference the key range 'D2:D1048576' (or 'D2:D65536' for old Excel).
    
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(FirstCellAddress)
    Dim krg As Range: Set krg = fCell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - fCell.Row + 1)
    ' The key range consists of the cells that will trigger...
    
    If Intersect(krg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' ... the following code when they are changed (manually or by VBA).
    
    ' Attempt to reference the old named range.
    
    Dim org As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set org = ws.Range(RangeName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim WasNotFound As Boolean: WasNotFound = org Is Nothing
    
    ' Attempt to reference the last non-empty cell in the key range.
    
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = krg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    
    ' Check if no cell found.
    
    If lCell Is Nothing Then
        If ShowMessages Then
            If WasNotFound Then
                MsgBox "No data in range """ & krg.Address(0, 0) & """." _
                    & vbLf & "The name """ & RangeName _
                    & """ does't exist.", vbCritical
            Else
                MsgBox "No data in range """ & krg.Address(0, 0) & """." _
                    & vbLf & "The name """ & RangeName _
                    & """ refers to the range """ & org.Address(0, 0) & """.", _
                    vbCritical
            End If
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the new named range.
    
    Dim nrg As Range: Set nrg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    
    ' Determine if the range reference doesn't have to be changed.
    
    Dim IsToBeChanged As Boolean
    
    If WasNotFound Then ' the name doesn't exist
        IsToBeChanged = True
    Else ' the name exists
        If Not nrg.Address = org.Address Then ' new and old are different
            IsToBeChanged = True
        'Else ' new and old are the same; do nothing
        End If
    End If
    
    If Not IsToBeChanged Then
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "The name """ & RangeName _
                & """ still refers to the range """ & org.Address(0, 0) _
                & """." & vbLf & "No change was required.", vbExclamation
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Create the name or change the range reference of the name.
    
    nrg.Name = RangeName
    
    If ShowMessages Then
        If WasNotFound Then
            MsgBox "The name """ & RangeName & """ didn't previously exist." _
                & vbLf & "It was created and refers to the range """ _
                & nrg.Address(0, 0) & """.", vbExclamation
        Else
            MsgBox "The range reference of the name """ & RangeName _
                & """ was changed from """ & org.Address(0, 0) & """ to """ _
                & nrg.Address(0, 0) & """.", vbInformation
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```